# list connected bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can I list all connected bluetooth devices on android ?

thanks!

Comment: Have you got the solution for this. I am searching for same, Please provide answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void checkConnected()
{
  // true == headset connected && connected headset is support hands free
  int state = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
  if (state != BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED)
    return;

  try
  {
    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileProxy(_context, serviceListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private ServiceListener serviceListener = new ServiceListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile)
  {

  }

  @Override
  public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy)
  {
    for (BluetoothDevice device : proxy.getConnectedDevices())
    {
      Log.i("onServiceConnected", "|" + device.getName() + " | " + device.getAddress() + " | " + proxy.getConnectionState(device) + "(connected = "
          + BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED + ")");
    }

    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().closeProfileProxy(profile, proxy);
  }
};
```

Comment: This works, but it's more like polling. Is there a way to have a nice callback of when the list changes? Using BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED, it's not quite the same as it's about pairing/bonding, and it's not reliable either (doesn't say when it finished bonding) .

Answer (score 3):

As of API 14 (Ice Cream), Android has a some new BluetoothAdapter methods including:

`public int getProfileConnectionState (int profile)`

where profile is one of `HEALTH, HEADSET, A2DP`

Check response, if it's not `STATE_DISCONNECTED` you know you have a live connection.

Here is code example that will work on any API device:

```
BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;

/**
 * Check if a headset type device is currently connected. 
 * 
 * Always returns false prior to API 14
 * 
 * @return true if connected
 */
public boolean isVoiceConnected() {
    boolean retval = false;
    try {
        Method method = mAdapter.getClass().getMethod("getProfileConnectionState", int.class);
        // retval = mAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) != android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
        retval = (Integer)method.invoke(mAdapter, 1) != 0;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        // nothing to do
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Hi Yossi, do you have some code for this? It would be great :)

Comment: That is returning me true always if I have bluetooth on, even if im not connected to anything

Comment: Simulator or actual device? Which device and Android version?

Comment: Android emulator to android device do you have any code for this?

Answer (score 2):

- First you need to retrieve the `BluetoothAdapter`:

> final BluetoothAdapter btAdapter =
>   BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

- Second you need to make sure Bluetooth is available and turned on :

> if (btAdapter != null && btAdapter.isEnabled()) // null means no
>   Bluetooth!

If the Bluetooth is not turned out you can either use `btAdapter.enable()` which is not recommended in the documentation or ask the user to do it : [Programmatically enabling bluetooth on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22562606/3535408)

- Third you need to define an array of states (to filter out
  unconnected devices):

> final int[] states = new int[] {BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED,
>   BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING};

- Fourth, you create a `BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener` which
  contains two callbacks triggered when a service is connected and
  disconnected :

  ```
  final BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener listener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
      @Override
      public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
      }
  };
  ```

---

Now since you have to repeat the querying process for all available Bluetooth Profiles in the Android SDK ([A2Dp, GATT, GATT_SERVER, Handset, Health, SAP](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#A2DP)) you should proceed as follow :

In `onServiceConnected`, place a condition that check what is the current profile so that we add the found devices into the correct collection and we use : `proxy.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(states)` to filter out unconnected devices:

```
switch (profile) {
    case BluetoothProfile.A2DP:
        ad2dpDevices.addAll(proxy.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(states));
        break;
    case BluetoothProfile.GATT: // NOTE ! Requires SDK 18 !
        gattDevices.addAll(proxy.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(states));
        break;
    case BluetoothProfile.GATT_SERVER: // NOTE ! Requires SDK 18 !
        gattServerDevices.addAll(proxy.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(states));
        break;
    case BluetoothProfile.HEADSET: 
        headsetDevices.addAll(proxy.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(states));
        break;
    case BluetoothProfile.HEALTH: // NOTE ! Requires SDK 14 !
        healthDevices.addAll(proxy.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(states));
        break;
    case BluetoothProfile.SAP: // NOTE ! Requires SDK 23 !
        sapDevices.addAll(proxy.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(states));
        break;
}
```

And finally, the last thing to do is start the querying process :

```
btAdapter.getProfileProxy(yourContext, listener, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
btAdapter.getProfileProxy(yourContext, listener, BluetoothProfile.GATT); // NOTE ! Requires SDK 18 !
btAdapter.getProfileProxy(yourContext, listener, BluetoothProfile.GATT_SERVER); // NOTE ! Requires SDK 18 !
btAdapter.getProfileProxy(yourContext, listener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
btAdapter.getProfileProxy(yourContext, listener, BluetoothProfile.HEALTH); // NOTE ! Requires SDK 14 !
btAdapter.getProfileProxy(yourContext, listener, BluetoothProfile.SAP); // NOTE ! Requires SDK 23 !
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34790442/2715054

Comment: I have one question. For some reason I get response only for HEADSET/A2DP/HEALTH devices. No other profile gets called.

Answer (score 1):

So you get the list of paired devices.

```
 BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevicesList = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();


    for (BluetoothDevice pairedDevice : pairedDevicesList) {
    Log.d("BT", "pairedDevice.getName(): " + pairedDevice.getName());
    Log.d("BT", "pairedDevice.getAddress(): " + pairedDevice.getAddress());

    saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), pairedDevice.getName(), pairedDevice.getAddress());

}
```

Comment: This will give you the list of "bonded" devices but you cannot get the connected state of the devices. Bonded just means that it had at one time been paired - not that it is currently connected. It is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Android system doesn't let you query for all "currently" connected devices. It however, you can query for paired devices. You will need to use a broadcast receiver to listen to ACTION_ACL_{CONNECTED|DISCONNECTED} events along with STATE_BONDED event to update your application states to track what's currently connected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it works on android 10

### Kotlin

```
private val serviceListener: ServiceListener = object : ServiceListener {
    var name: String? = null
    var address: String? = null
    var threadName: String? = null
    override fun onServiceDisconnected(profile: Int) {}
    override fun onServiceConnected(profile: Int, proxy: BluetoothProfile) {
        for (device in proxy.connectedDevices) {
            name = device.name
            address = device.address
            threadName = Thread.currentThread().name
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "$name $address$threadName",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            Log.i(
                "onServiceConnected",
                "|" + device.name + " | " + device.address + " | " + proxy.getConnectionState(
                    device
                ) + "(connected = "
                        + BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED + ")"
            )
        }
        BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().closeProfileProxy(profile, proxy)
    }
}
```

### Call this method in main thread

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
            .getProfileProxy(this, serviceListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)
```

### Java

[original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308359/12119438)

Comment: Hi Kirill, thanks for answering this question. I hope you could also suggest if there is any way that I can get the list of previously connected bluetooth devices like it shows in the system bluetooth settings. I have raised a question for the same here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67041292/react-native-get-previously-connected-bluetooth-devices

Answer (score -1):

Please analyze [**this class**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/DeviceListActivity.html) online.

Here you will find how to discover all connected (paired) Bluetooth devices.

Comment: hi Desiderio, well as I said I want to list the connected (active) devices, not the paired/trusted ones.

Comment: What about monitoring broadcasts ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED?

Comment: How can I download that class? I think it will help me on my problem.

Comment: DeviceListActivity.java class is part of your android install. Just explore Android folder.

Answer (score -1):

Well here are the steps:

1. First, you start intent to discover devices

   `IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);`
2. Register a broadcast reciver for it:

   `registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);`
3. On the definition of mReceiver:

   ```
   private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       String action = intent.getAction();
       // When discovery finds a device
       if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
           // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
           BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
           // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
           arrayadapter.add(device.getName())//arrayadapter is of type ArrayAdapter<String>
           lv.setAdapter(arrayadapter); //lv is the list view 
           arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   }
   ```

and the list will be automatically populated on new device discovery.

Comment: There is a missing }; at the end of the code. I cannot make the edit myself as it has to be a 6 character change, and it is only missing 2.

Comment: This is for use with discovery, this is not for a list of already connected devices. see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()