# is it possible to switch bluetooth dual modes (BLE/BT => BLE only for example) programmatically for Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have currently a pulse oximeter device which provides BLE and BT Classic dual mode. 
However it always pops up the message with "Disconnected" when i try to pair device, but according to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58942 I think it is a bug. and also I found this as well, https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_cc256x/f/660/t/345865

so ... I'm just wondering whether there is a way to switch dual mode to single mode, for example, BLE only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562606/programmatically-enabling-bluetooth-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android

Comment: these links may be helpful