# Is there a way to check if a specific connected bluetooth device is active or not in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

For my program, I need to be able to determine if a specific Bluetooth device is active when multiple Bluetooth devices are connected. I am aware of how to check if a specific Bluetooth device is connected, but a device being active is different because any audio played from the transmitter will only be played on the active Bluetooth device unless dual audio for Bluetooth is turned on.

Comment: [have a look at the similar question answered, this might help you!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932228/list-connected-bluetooth-devices)

Comment: i will send few links.it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-can-i-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected